# How to scrape Request cookies from a Website in Python 3.0+?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, session-cookies

To acquire data from the web is sometimes more demanding than expected, with multiple necessary steps included to get a status code of 200. And sadly, that happens to be the case for me.

I am trying to scrape data of Implied Volatility, which is displayed in a chart with a green line on [this](https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/AAPL/IV/) site for in this case Apple under "IV30".
Logged in, you'll be able to view that data. But this data actually comes from [this](https://%20https://marketchameleon.com/ivCharts/getIV30_histChartData) URL. I found that out by going to the network tab, XHR/fetch, getIV30_histChartData (where you can see the numbers under "prieview"), copying the file as curl, and then converting it to a Python request online at [this](https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html) website, you can retrieve the IV data rendered in the chart. But this requires a number of cookies that are very temporary:

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'bm_sv': 'B090169341AC61245C36E7CC8101E5FB~YAAQLZbvUDhjyeJAQAAKSnNLRRyG/DC6xpzHD1QYSvPV2siYUnDqy8Uc8cVUjHyW124O0kjRl5yV4mMYjzhT3DVWrXNlKdEMVDxynKwBzV4HGMO74uARNXH8fCNp7YHAWEI/z8v/GEpZx7AEaELi3kKexMpuegjNK94hVruL9rqnB4IgZnJPZuz43528cZDvYYeNMy4Cbrif9LuqOp3mD9QW7KeTnjUrJIHbB24Vt77Qr05SqaEjVNF1gDtFk5CZ7LiO3evRQg==~1',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.862382208.168676567503',
    '_ga_CXRDD1LJF1': 'GS1.1.1689690300.36.1.16886921566.0.0.0',
    'RT': 'z=1&dm=marketchameleon.com&si=p9h4ivefgze&ss=lix2qe26&sl=0&tt=0',
    '_okbk': 'vi3%3Dinactive%2Ccd4%3Dtrue%2Cvi5%3D0%2Cvi4%3D1688690539571%2Cvi2%3Dfalse%2Cvi1%3Dfalse%2Ccd8%3%vs%2Ccd6%3D0%2Ccd5%3Daway%2Ccd3%3Dfalse%2Ccd2%3D0%2Ccd1%3D0%2C',
    'hblid': 'q6rVp2ksgCgTyC8o1BM0Np5FypoBAE',
    'olfsk': 'olfsk8023426482735985',
    'wcsid': 'lc2NlWDwxkrYVWpOo1BM0NyFop5ApE0',
    '_oklv': '1688690538229%c2NlWDwskrXcHpO8o1BM0NyFop5ApE0',
    'ak_bmsc': '84B8B78764C7C685WRN&8B23CEB40460~000000000000000000000000000000~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',
    'bm_mi': '626CCC05A702F4A419861B16FC27C990~YAAQFZbvUIQlfCSJAQAAiA3JLRQOdcr1ymsM5ucl9pibJc0A4V58ld1V0vWvwSsik8g6SLOPjKSTUelGHrpbS+Zg8qcsf1k7a4WZ34Jmu/BajkyMzIb0pUAP4+jtI6YbysrXqqE//js8TMme7e9Ct0yUvt8Yv/XCi0phu+LQWBQGx54wsnNtdpTCipuPV7deZa2iFD0Qt9klJyKSpEYU50cm/xPI2jpYuKoU8LsyCsUAxLHY2FkG1xdEySenWnG1jOXfCk9bOi8LmKpSN3nkCTTUnRpyFvc25hL+GVKnDyk/bLWRezYiWb8xkQ/UIy2iM/ciJHmGJOKrltFbHM9slXA==~1',
    '.AspNet.ApplicationCookie': '1L7QgsPjevZq-DFlrPNmQrGin-JEX5TFKr5LoQdzE1z397qYuDXtJxbyPFOcXRiA8Er-e9IKYSbpnE2BpsMUX77cSVLt3jVWwySbVZ25vCDQvibWg-51BxBFG_v028e3DgQ3nzv3g0oaq-znfdYkXIFphhwWmMHrxE3ikMzNqpiSdmCEH09r5GSZbcPmdmT5DGdU9gxUym8UIPzb9_RmnkoBe4FCrNP7ZJy8IMzAWjbkQ3hq_aO4VKDYIKUoRX3oHKbc3IGbcTCZGV8xe_9nsudYfsr-Cw88_8cdAa8dDk8-S_av5UpBzQCEHwMlpCtCG8th_tuSVWS9yc8b1SKvesxXMgGs0NLNcppzG-BFBU-KZG_dgrLgMy3=874Hcy5sg30UGdtUE1Ppp6kmaSftjWAXg-mXMm6abVJc7Ak6hhc9XBa_qFGT4aryzop6AS2MjfcI8PQtrIGs23WhaNIqw',
    'v1': '59307285',
    '__RequestVerificationToken': 'tNHCniRtDt62gFrppLBrE3HRj-rnoDpEMG_cUv3AC_jGE7_sTtBxqZieouEfYXsrVjE3DWn-C8FZv3sthxBDAewJU3r3UlSq0XWQKzOi2z6uE1',
    '_ok': '5515-851-10-1508',
    '_okdetect': '%7B%22token%22%3A%221688669123744350%22%2C%22proto%22%3A%22about%3A%22%2C%22host%22%3A%22%22%7D',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': '5lqw2riulwrknp3ugcue1mbj',
    'g_state': '{"i_p":168713434334001,"i_l":3}',
    'PAPVisitorId': 'rpIs4v1o2JIRblGTouhBsBfAyaA0NMvT',
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Host': 'marketchameleon.com',
    'Origin': 'https://marketchameleon.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Referer': 'https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/AAPL/IV/',
    'Content-Length': '6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-MobDisp': 'false',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = {
  'p': '6699'
}

response = requests.post('https://marketchameleon.com/ivCharts/getIV30_histChartData', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

(The code would look something like this if you followed the same steps. **OBS**: This code is not valid though.)

Thus these request cookies that are used whilst scraping the URL opt to be the difference-maker for the scraping of the IV-numbers.

The website is protected with **Akamai** bot protection services. To try and use Selenium to log in to this site beforehand might be an option if you can go around it.

I have so far tried *some* methods to get these request-cookies, that sure do get cookies, but only a handful. I have never gotten enough of them to make a successful scraping-request.

Here are my methods:
First I found this version:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = 'https://marketchameleon.com/ivCharts/getIV30_histChartData'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Host': 'marketchameleon.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
print(cookies)
```

But it only gives the 'ak_bmsc' cookie, and with a second request maybe even the 'bm_sv' cookie. But that's it. Keep in mind that the cookies that we're seeking are not response-cookies, but the less often scraped request-cookies.

Here's an image of them:

[image: Request Cookies]

Which is why this won't work. This consequently leads to however we can get the so-called request-cookies? Hence I tried this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

def get_cookies():
    with driver:
        driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/ivCharts/getIV30_histChartData')
        time.sleep(10)
        driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        cookie = {c['name']:c['value'] for c in driver_cookies}
    return cookie

print(get_cookies())
```

But although this provides more cookies ('v1', 'ASP.NET_SessionId' and 'ak_bmsc'), it still doesn't give all the necessary cookies.
The full a complete cookie-name-list comes along with the url is made up of the following cookies, which are also shown with an attached image for clarification:

```py
RT, 
g_state,
_okdetect,
ak_bmsc,
bm_sv,
wcsid,
_ok,
v1,
_oklv,
_okbk,
_ga,
_ga_CXRDD1LJF1,
olfsk,
ASP.NET_SessionId,
hblid,
PAPVisitorId,
.AspNet.ApplicationCookie
```

How would you guys go about to try and get these request cookies? And in that case, how would I do the same? All tips and tricks are welcomed!

~ A scraper in need

Comment: What is your final goal? Only cookie collection?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve data on Implied volatility. This is displayed on the page below with whatever (US) stock you, please. E.g. this page uses APPLE, [link](https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/AAPL/IV/). Logged in, you'll be able to view the data (IV30) a whole year from now back. But this chart is rendered from the URL above. I found out that by going to the network tab, XHR/fetch, getIV30_histChartData (where you can go to preview, where the numbers are shown), copying the file as curl, and then converting it to a Python request online, as the cookies are used there. @undetected Selenium